# Regarding sampling and multiplying/applying convolution in time/frequency domains

Tags: experimental-physics, time, fourier-transform, frequency, experimental-technique

In lectures we have looked at sampling, and I see that it seems to always be that we multiply I the time domain and apply convolution in the frequency domain.

For example, we multiply by the delta comb in the time domain and apply convolution with corresponding delta comb in the frequency domain; or sampling for some finite time is multiplying by some window function which is a convolution by this function in the Fourier domain.

Maybe my trouble lies in not really knowing what it is that we DO when we sample. What happens?

Why do we multiply by some signal in time?

Could we multiply in the frequency domain instead?

Why/why not?

What is it about each of these domains that makes them accessible in different ways, and allows us to do these different operations within them?

Answer (score 1):

When you sample a signal you produce a series of samples, each of which is scaled according to the value of the original continuous time signal at some point in time. If you want to represent the sampled signal in the continuous time domain, you have a sequence of periodically spaced impulses:

$$x_s(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x(nT)\delta(t-nT)$$

where $T$ is the sampling period.

As you can see, this is represented mathematically by multiplying $x(t)$ by the delta function.

This is represented in the frequency domain by convolution because of the property of the fourier transform

$${\mathcal F}[x(t)y(t)] = {\mathcal F}[x(t)]\star{\mathcal F}[y(t)]$$

where $\mathcal F[\cdot]$ is the fourier transform operator and $\star$ is the convolution operator.